# Search Query with Umlaut (äöü) not working

Tags: magento-1, search, catalogsearch, character-encoding

Search Query with Umlaut (äöü) not working, what can i do?
[image: here i entered the keyword grün]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL after form submission *should* be:

```
/catalogsearch/result?q=gr%C3%BCn
```

where `%C3%BC` is `ü` in UTF-8, URL encoded.

But it is

```
/catalogsearch/result?q=gr%25C3%25BCn
```

where `%25` is `%` URL encoded. So the URL encoding is applied twice when the form is submitted.

This can happen with incorrectly configured redirects (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520484/mod-rewrite-urlencoding-an-already-urlencoded-querystring-parameter-any-way-to) and as I checked your site, there is indeed a redirect when I submit the search form. So fix the rewrite/redirect configuration in your `.htaccess` or virtual host configuration.

You can try it out: With the default `.htaccess` from Magento it should work.