# Catalog Search Sorting Broken With Umlauts / Special Characters

Tags: search, catalogsearch, magento1.9.3

There is a catalog search Magento bug in 1.9.3.0 - 1.9.3.4. You can reproduce it like that:

1. Create a product with an umlaut in the name like "über".
2. Search for the umlaut like "ü" in the frontend.
3. Search results are shown. Now change the sorting from "relevance" (default) to e.g. "name".
4. Encounter the bug:

   1. [expected] see the results ordered by name.
   2. [actual] see a broken page:

[image: Magento 1.9.3 Catalog Search Umlauts Bug]

Mind that this is NOT an `.htaccess` issue as described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136151/142). How can this be solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catalogsearch encodes query string for sort/limit in toolbar](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177055/catalogsearch-encodes-query-string-for-sort-limit-in-toolbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was awfully hard to debug, but in the end, the solution is easy.

The links for the sorting are inserted in an escaped manner into the page. Example:

```
<option value="http://shop.local/catalogsearch/result/index/?dir=asc&amp;order=name&amp;q=%C3%BC">Name</option>
```

When the select element is changed, the function `setLocation(this.value)` from `js/varien/js.js` is called. It basically simply does a

```
`window.location.href = url;`
```

Unfortunately, since Magento 1.9.3.0, the implementation has been extended with an `encodeURI`:

```
`window.location.href = encodeURI(url);`
```

This means that these links are encoded twice. Once when inserted into the page (mind the `%C3%BC` in the option value above) and once when switching the location. Then, the param `%25C3%25BC` (`%` is encoded with `%25`) is sent to the server, so that the request fails.

My solution was to override the template `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` and change the following call:

```
$this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc')
```

to:

```
rawurldecode($this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc'))
```

Mind that you also need to wrap the `getLimitUrl` call!

Not sure if this is the most elegant or most secure solution, but it works at least ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Simon for the correct analysis of the bug. Magento Core changed but the theme didn't.

Your proposed solution works but i don’t like getting an encoded value from the block, decoding it with `rawurldecode` and encoding it again in function `setLocation`.

So my solution is as follows:

Just change the onChange-handler of the order select element in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` from

```
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
```

to

```
<select onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
```

As `setLocation` only performs a call to `encodeURI` we can safely remove the call to `setLocation` and set the window url directly as we know the url is  encoded. Function `setLocation` for reference:

```
function setLocation(url){
    window.location.href = encodeURI(url);
}
```